# Основное и второстепенное значение букв.Проверьте,пожалуйста.

Tags: русская-графика

Светлана (оовоооов). Буквы в основном значении - с, в, т, л, а, н (их 6); буквы во второстепенном значении - е, а (их 2).

давно (ооооо). Буквы в основном значении - д, а, в, н, о (их 5).

мечтала (овоооов). Буквы в основном значении - м, ч, т, а, л (их 5); буквы во второстепенном значении - е, а (их 2).

остаться (вооовввв). Буквы в основном значении - с, т, а (их 3); буквы во второстепенном значении - о, т, ь, с, я (их 5).

дома (ооов). Буквы в основном значении - д, о, м (их3); буквы во второстепенном значении - а (их 1).

одна (вооо). Буквы в основном значении - д, н, а (их 3); буквы во второстепенном значении - о (их 1).

Ей (оо). Буквы в основном значении - е, й (их 2).

очень (оовоо). Буквы в основном значении - о, ч, н, ь (их 4); буквы во второстепенном значении - е (их 1).

хотелось (овооовоо). Буквы в основном значении - х, т, е, л, с, ь (их 6); буквы во второстепенном значении - о, о (их 2).

самой (овооо). Буквы в основном значении - с, м, о, й (их 4); буквы во второстепенном значении - а (их 1).

похозяйничать (ововооооовоо). Буквы в основном значении - п, х, з, я, й, н, и, ч, т, ь (их 10); буквы во второстепенном значении - о, о, а (их 3).

повозиться (ововоовввв). Буквы в основном значении - п, в, з, и (их 4); буквы во второстепенном значении - о, о, т, ь, с, я (их 6).

с (о) Алешкой (воооово). Буквы в основном значении - л, ё, ш, к, й (их 5); буквы во второстепенном значении - а, о (их 2).

чтобы (воооо). Буквы в основном значении - т, о, б, ы (их 4); буквы во второстепенном значении - ч (их 1).

никто (ооооо). Буквы в основном значении - н, и, к, т, о (их 5).

не (ов). Буквы в основном значении - н (их 1); буквы во второстепенном значении - е (их 1).

мешал (овооо). Буквы в основном значении - м, ш, а, л (их 4); буквы во второстепенном значении - е (их 1).

ни (оо). Буквы в основном значении - с, в, т, л, а, н (их 6); буквы во второстепенном значении - е, а (их 2).

папа (ооов). Буквы в основном значении - п, а, п (их 3); буквы во второстепенном значении -а (их 1).

ни (оо). Буквы в основном значении - н, и (их 2).

мама (ооов). Буквы в основном значении - м, а, м (их 3); буквы во второстепенном значении -а (их1).

ни (оо). Буквы в основном значении - н, и (их 2).

бабушка (оооооов). Буквы в основном значении - б, а, б, у, ш, к (их 6); буквы во второстепенном значении - а (их 1).

Comment: Ну и зачем оно в таком виде?

Comment: А какой вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

давно (овооо). Буквы в основном значении - д, в, н, о (их 5). Буква во второстеп. знач. - а (1).

похозяйничать (ововоооооовоо) - пропустили одну букву.

Чтобы никто не мешал - правильно.

Дальше путаница, получается "чтобы никто не мешал ни Светлана папа ни мама ни бабушка"

Надо: чтобы никто не  мешал Светлан**е** - ни папа, ни мама, ни бабушка.

Нужно "НИ "перенести после "Светлане" и записать само слово "Светлане", а то у Вас только перечислены буквы, а слова нет.

Буквы в основном значении - с, в, т, л, а, н (их 6); буквы во второстепенном значении -е, **е**(их 2).

Остальное верно.